# UserPrincipals.GetAuthorizationGroups An error (1301) occurred while enumerating the groups. After upgrading to Server 2012 Domain Controller

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller

**Research:**

[Similar Issue with workaround, but not actual solution to existing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341620/userprincipals-getauthorizationgroups-an-error-1301-occurred-while-enumerating)

[Similar issue pointing to Microsoft End Point update as culprit](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/756007/getauthorizationgroups-not-returning-sgs-even-though-ldap-queries-returns-appropriate-result)

The above links are the most suited to my problem,  I have also viewed every similar question listed by Stack Overflow upon creating this post, and only the above referenced questions fit my issue.

**Background:**

I have been using `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` for permissions for specific page access running IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2 in a C#.NET 4.0 web forms site for 2 and a half years.  On May 15 2013 we removed a primary Domain controller running Server 2008 (not r2) and replaced it with a Server 2012 Domain Controller.  The next day we started receiving the exception listed below.

I use Principal Context for Forms Authentication.  The username/pass handshake succeeds and the auth cookie is properly set, but the subsequent Principal Context call that also calls `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` fails intermittently.  We've resolved a few BPA issues that appeared in the Server 2012 Domain Controller but this has yet to resolve the issue.  I also instituted a cron that runs on two separate servers.  The two servers will fail at Group SID resolution at different times though they are running the same code base.  (A dev environment and production environment).

The issue resolves itself temporarily upon web server reboot, and also on the dev server it will resolve itself after 12 hours of not functioning.  The production server will usually stop functioning properly until a reboot without resolving itself.

At this point I am trying to refine the cron targeting specific Domain Controllers in the network as well as the new DC and using the standard LDAP query that is currently failing to yield more targeted exception times.  Thus far we've found on one web server that there is no pattern to the days at which it fails, but it will recover within roughly 12 hours.  The latest results show Group SID resolution failure between 8AM-8PM then it recovers, several days later it will fail at 8pm and recover at 8am then run fine for another 12 hours and fail again.  We are hoping to see if it is just a specific server communication issue or to see if it is the entire set of Domain Controllers.

**Exception:**

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: PrincipalOperationException 
Exception message: An error (1301) occurred while enumerating the groups.  
The group's SID could not be resolved.
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SidList.TranslateSids(String target, IntPtr[] pSids)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SidList..ctor(SID_AND_ATTR[] sidAndAttr)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet..ctor(Byte[] userSid, NetCred credentials, ContextOptions contextOptions, String flatUserAuthority, StoreCtx userStoreCtx, Object userCtxBase)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOfAZ(Principal p)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```

**Question:**

Given the above information, does anyone have any idea why decommissioning the Windows Server 2008 (not r2) and implementing a new Server 2012 DC would cause `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` to fail with the 1301 SID resolution error?
Ideas on eliminating possible causes would also be appreciated.

**Disclaimer:**

This is my first post to Stack Overflow, I often research here but have not joined in discussions until now.  Forgive me if I should have posted elsewhere and feel free to point out better steps before posting.

**UPDATE 13-JUN-2013:**

On the 12th of June I addressed the possibility of items not disposed causing the issue.
The time frame has been too short to determine if the adjusted code has fixed the issue, but I will continue to update as we work towards a resolution such that maybe with any luck someone here can lend a hand.

Original Code

```
    public bool isGroupMember(string userName, ArrayList groupList)
    {
        bool valid = false;

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain_server + ".domain.org:636", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);

            // find the user in the identity store
            UserPrincipal user =
                UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                    ctx,
                    userName);

            // get the groups for the user principal and
            // store the results in a PrincipalSearchResult object
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups =
                user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            // display the names of the groups to which the
            // user belongs
            foreach (Principal group in groups)
            {
                foreach (string groupName in groupList)
                {
                    if (group.ToString() == groupName)
                    {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        return valid;
    }
```

Updated Code

```
        public bool isGroupMember(string userName, ArrayList groupList, string domain_server)
        {
        bool valid = false;

            try
            {

                using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain_server + ".domain.org:636", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer))
                {

                    // find the user in the identity store
                    UserPrincipal user =
                        UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                            ctx,
                            userName);

                    try
                    {
                        // get the groups for the user principal and
                        // store the results in a PrincipalSearchResult object
                        using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
                        {
                            // display the names of the groups to which the
                            // user belongs

                            foreach (Principal group in groups)
                            {
                                foreach (string groupName in groupList)
                                {

                                    if (group.ToString() == groupName)
                                    {
                                        valid = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                group.Dispose();

                            }
                        }//end using-2
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        log_gen("arbitrary info");
                        return false;
                    }
                }//end using-1
            }
            catch
            {
                log_gen("arbitrary info");
                return false;
            }

        return valid;

    }
```

Comment: **Update:**
There may be an issue with not disposing PrincipalSearchResult.  Though I'm not sure why it would just now be an issue after two years.
I'm currently enclosing the iEnumerable items in [using] statements while trying to track down issues via perfmon. 
[Resource on Leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715159/does-principalsearchresultt-automatically-dispose-all-elements-in-its-collecti)

Comment: **Update:** Still had a few bits of code that were not properly disposing.  Updated today and will continue to monitor the issue.  The group SID enumeration failure occurred every 12 hours over the weekend, and resolved itself every 12 hours. We've added more variables to the issue which I erroneously posted as "May 14" but actually started on "May 16th", a host of .NET updates were installed on the 15th via windows update.

Comment: **Update:** Major code re-factoring as I learn more about proper disposal.  I'm still new to C# and inherited this project so a good bit to update.  The issue is still occurring, and I'm still optimizing code hoping for the best.  At some point I will roll back the .NET updates that were installed on the 15th of May and see if things iron out, but for now I'll continue to correct poorly implemented code.

Comment: **Update:**  The dev server has been stable for 8 days, as opposed to going down every few days.  The production server is still functioning terribly.  The 12 hour fail window is still holding strong.  A reboot yesterday at 7:48 AM to restore functionality was followed up roughly 12 hours later at 7:54 PM causing the error again.  **slams skull into desk**

Comment: **Update:** I've halted code updates for now and am using perfmon to get a grasp as to what the server is doing at the point of failure, and roughly what is going on 12 hours prior since it seems to die in 12 hour increments.  The production server had run for 36 hours without issue until an update yesterday caused a reboot. (yay for new sccm install performing maintenance at improper times, yet another thing to fix) The Kernel shutdown initiated at 4:11:34PM, the website was running again at 4:15:23PM.  The SID error started occurring again at 4:15:05AM.  Roughly 12 hours after the updates.

Comment: **Update:** I obviously don't know enough about Perfmon to glean any useful info short of the fact that everything appears stable.  Heap Sizes / Collections / Virtual & Private Byte among a few other sets that have been monitored.  Still no discernible cause of the SID enumeration failure.  In spinning up a new project on the Dev environment we had to install .NET 4.5, I had a glimmer of hope that perhaps that minor tweak would alleviate the issue.  It did not.  We are spinning up a Server 2012 dev environment shortly to see if it suffers the same woes.

Comment: **Update:** The issue is on the back burner for now while new functionality is added to the site.  We've instituted the work around listed at the very top of the question, but still have the troublesome code running in the background to monitor the failures and will return to solving this issue when time allows.

Comment: Hi @Pynt , we've just encountered the same issue as you and have moved away from 2012 for now as a workaround.  I was just wondering if you got any further with this issue beyond your workaround?

Comment: @Johnny Reilly, No progress to report other than the below two answers as possibilities.  I'm in a position with too many duties and not enough man hours or help to progress with this situation due to the work around being functional.  I have a deadline of April 1st to migrate our webserver to Core 2012 installation which will allow me to test the answer given by Gary Hill, but I hope to have that accomplished well before that time frame.  Sorry, I have nothing new to add at this time.

Comment: We got the same issue few weeks ago. As I read your story and the different answers, I can confirm that the problem is most likely the one pointed by @Gary Hill below.
We have a dev server on 2008 R2 and a prod server in 2012. One day we implemented some rights according to AD groups. It worked fine on 2012 but our dev server was doomed. We found out that when we implemented a new secondary AD server on 2012, the dev server was linked to it, while other servers linked to primary AD on 2008 R2 were fine. And also explain some issues we experienced between the 2 AD.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have just run into this same issue and the info I have managed to track down may be helpful; as above we have seen this problem where the domain controller is running Server 2012 - firstly with a customer deployment and then replicated on our own network.

After some experimentation we found that our code would run fine on Server 2012, but hit the 1301 error code when the client system was running Server 2008. The key information about what was happening was found here:

[MS blog translated from German](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://blogs.technet.com/b/deds/archive/2013/08/12/probleme-mit-dem-umwandeln-von-sids-in-namen.aspx)

The hotfix referred to in the link below has fixed the problem on our test system

[SID S-1-18-1 and SID S-1-18-2 can't be mapped](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830145)

Hope this is helpful for someone! As many have noted this method call seems rather fragile and we will probably look at implementing some alternative approach before we hit other issues.

Gary

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This was our last line of thinking around June 27th when we spun up a Server 2012 dev environment.  Sadly resources were pushed elsewhere before we were able to implement this test.  However, I believe recent events may direct me back to migrating everything to the 2012 environment.  Between your comment and the one above I believe the situation will be resolved.  I will mark an answer once time is allowed for me to fully test.

Comment: I did test this update for our windows 7 machines and found that it did resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the hotfix! It solves our problem!

Comment: Danke, solved issue for me. (Win 2008 R2 connect to Win 2012 AD server)

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution. It seems to work consistently well. Because the problem happens when iterating over the collection, I use a different approach when iterating in order to handle the exception without blocking the actual iterating:

```
private string[] GetUserRoles(string Username)
{    
    List<string> roles = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        string domain = Username.Contains("\\") ? Username.Substring(0, Username.IndexOf("\\")) : string.Empty;
        string username = Username.Contains("\\") ? Username.Substring(Username.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) : Username;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, username);
            if (user != null)
            {
                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                int count = groups.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Principal> principalCollection = groups.Skip(i).Take(1);
                    Principal principal = null;
                    try
                    {
                        principal = principalCollection.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Error handling...
                        //Known exception - sometimes AD can't query a particular group, requires server hotfix?
                        //http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830145
                    }

                    if (principal!=null && principal is GroupPrincipal)
                    {
                        GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = (GroupPrincipal)principal;
                        if (groupPrincipal != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupPrincipal.Name))
                        {
                            roles.Add(groupPrincipal.Name.Trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Error handling...
    }
    return roles.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. Although I don't love empty catches, it will skip the AD group that it cannot read and continue on.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me reading the groups, anyway this was far too slow for users with more than 100 groups as it took quite a time until the Exception rises.
I found a different approach and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180438/9758687

Answer (score 4):

We experienced this issue when our infrastructure team brought a 2012 Domain Controller online.  We also had pre-2012 DCs in place and so we experienced the issue intermittently.  We came up with a fix which I wanted to share - it has 2 parts.

First of all, install the [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830145) mentioned by Gary Hill.  This will resolve the following issue:

> An error (1301) occurred while enumerating the groups.   The group's SID could not be resolved.

We thought we were home free after installing this hotfix.  However, after it was installed we got a different intermittent error.  Certain groups that we were interrogating had a null `sAMAccountName` property.  The actual property *was* populated in Active Directory but it was incorrectly being returned with a null value by the API.  I presume this is a bug somewhere in the Active Directory API but I don't know any more than that.

Fortunately we were able to work around the issue by switching to use the group `Name` property instead of the `sAMAccountName` property.  This worked for us.  I believe, that `sAMAccountName` is effectively deprecated and exists only for backwards compatibility reasons.  That being the case it seemed a reasonable change to make.

I enclose a cut down version of our `GetRolesForUser` code to demonstrate the change in place.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domainName))
{
    try
    {
        var p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
        if (p == null) throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity returned null for user: {0}, this can indicate a problem with one or more of the AD controllers", username));

        var groups = p.GetAuthorizationGroups();
        var domain = username.Substring(0, username.IndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToLower();

        foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Name))
            {
                var domainGroup = domain + @"\" + group.Name.ToLower();

                if (_groupsToUse.Any(x => x.Equals(domainGroup, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    // Go through each application role defined and check if the AD domain group is part of it
                    foreach (string role in roleKeys)
                    {
                        string[] roleMembers = new [] { "role1", "role2" };

                        foreach (string member in roleMembers)
                        {
                            // Check if the domain group is part of the role
                            if (member.ToLower().Contains(domainGroup))
                            {
                                // Cache the Application Role (NOT the AD role)
                                results.Add(role);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            group.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ProviderException("Unable to query Active Directory.", ex);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced error code 1301 with `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` while using a brand new virtual development domain which contained 2 workstations and 50 users/groups (many of which are the built in ones). We were running Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials with two Windows 8.1 Enterprise workstations joined to the domain.

I was able to recursively obtain a list of a user's group membership using the following code:

```
class ADGroupSearch
{
    List<String> groupNames;

    public ADGroupSearch()
    {
        this.groupNames = new List<String>();
    }

    public List<String> GetGroups()
    {
        return this.groupNames;
    }

    public void AddGroupName(String groupName)
    {
        this.groupNames.Add(groupName);
    }

    public List<String> GetListOfGroupsRecursively(String samAcctName)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, System.Environment.UserDomainName);
        Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAcctName);
        if (principal == null)
        {
            return GetGroups();
        }
        else
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> searchResults = principal.GetGroups();

            if (searchResults != null)
            {
                foreach (GroupPrincipal sr in searchResults)
                {
                    if (!this.groupNames.Contains(sr.Name))
                    {
                        AddGroupName(sr.Name);
                    }
                    Principal p = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sr.SamAccountName);

                    try
                    {
                        GetMembersForGroup(p);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //ignore errors and continue
                    }
                }

            }
            return GetGroups();
        }

    }



    private void GetMembersForGroup(Principal group)
    {
        if (group != null && typeof(GroupPrincipal) == group.GetType())
        {
            GetListOfGroupsRecursively(group.SamAccountName);
        } 
    }

    private bool IsGroup(Principal principal)
    {
        return principal.StructuralObjectClass.ToLower().Equals("group");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in an environment with multiple domain forests and trusts. I have pretty much this exact same code running on a web site form used to perform user security group lookups across the different domains.

I get this exact error in one of the very large domains where group membership can include 50+ different groups. It works fine in other domains forests.

In my research I found a thread that looks unrelated, but actually has the same stack trace. It is for a remote application running on SBS. The thread mentions that the error is caused by unresolvable SIDS in a group. I believe these would be what are known as "tombstoned" SIDS in active directory. [See the thread here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89318760-465a-4339-8cbf-3e1579b24d44/rwa-sbs-2011-server-error-in-remote-application-an-error-87-occurred-while-enumerating-the).

The thread suggests that finding the tombstoned enteries and removing them from the groups solves the problem. Is it possible the error you are receiving is because SIDS are getting tombstoned every 12 hours by a separate unrelated process? Ultimately, I believe this is a bug in the framework, and that the method should not crash because of tombstoned/unresolvable SIDS.

Good luck!

Comment: I read a bit on the unresolved SID issue prior to putting this task on the back burner, but I will revisit this possible cause at some point.  Luckily for me we are not in a federated setup at the moment so only 1 domain to worry about.  I don't believe that our AD list will take a large amount of time to validate for orphaned SID's.  Unfortunately they have me on a 6 month task at the moment so there is no telling when my free time will allow for this test.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested this is a VB.NET version of the same code. 
Few things you have to do before this code can work

1) You have to reference the assembly System.DirectoryServices

2) Make sure to pass "theusername" variable without the domain, so if your domain is "GIS" and your username is "Hussein" Windows generally authenticate you as GIS\Hussein. So you have to send in just purely the username "Hussein". I worked out the case sensitive stuff.

3) The method GetGroupsNew takes a username and returns a list of groups

4) The method isMemberofnew takes a username and a group and verifies that this user is part of that group or not, this is the one I was interested in.

```
Private Function getGroupsNew(theusername As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim lstGroups As New List(Of String)
    Try

        Dim allDomains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Cast(Of Domain)()

        Dim allSearcher = allDomains.[Select](Function(domain)
                                                  Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain.Name))

                                                  searcher.Filter = [String].Format("(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=*{0}*)))", theusername)

                                                  Return searcher

                                              End Function)

        Dim directoryEntriesFound = allSearcher.SelectMany(Function(searcher) searcher.FindAll().Cast(Of SearchResult)().[Select](Function(result) result.GetDirectoryEntry()))

        Dim memberOf = directoryEntriesFound.[Select](Function(entry)
                                                          Using entry
                                                              Return New With { _
                                                               Key .Name = entry.Name, _
                                                               Key .GroupName = DirectCast(entry.Properties("MemberOf").Value, Object()).[Select](Function(obj) obj.ToString()) _
                                                              }
                                                          End Using

                                                      End Function)



        For Each user As Object In memberOf
            For Each groupName As Object In user.GroupName
                lstGroups.Add(groupName)
            Next
        Next

        Return lstGroups

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function

Private Function isMemberofGroupNew(theusername As String, thegroupname As String) As Boolean

    Try

        Dim lstGroups As List(Of String) = getGroupsNew(theusername)

        For Each sGroup In lstGroups
            If sGroup.ToLower.Contains(thegroupname.ToLower) Then Return True
        Next

        Return False


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that if i am connected over VPN and use `groups=UserPrincipal.GetGroups()` then the Exception occures when iterating over the groups.

If someone want to read all groups of a user there is following possibility (which is faster than using `GetGroups()`)

```
private IList<string> GetUserGroupsLDAP(string samAccountName)
{
    var groupList = new List<string>();
    var domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + serverName, serverUser, serverUserPassword); // probably you don't need username and password

    var samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
    samSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
    samSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" + samAccountName + ")";

    var samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();
    if (samResult != null)
    {
        var theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
        theUser.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });

        var sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        sidSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
        sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        sidSearcher.Filter = CreateFilter(theUser);

        foreach (SearchResult result in sidSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            groupList.Add((string)result.Properties["name"][0]);
        }
    }
    return groupList;
}

private string CreateFilter(DirectoryEntry theUser)
{
    string filter = "(|";
    foreach (byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"])
    {
        var SID = new SecurityIdentifier(resultBytes, 0);
        filter += "(objectSid=" + SID.Value + ")";
    }
    filter += ")";
    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue after upgrading the domain controller to 2012.  Suddenly my call to user.GetAuthorizationGroups() started failing; I was getting the same exception you were (error 1301).  So, I changed it to user.GetGroups().  That worked for a little while, then started failing intermittently on "bad username or password".  My latest workaround appears to fix it, for the moment at least.  Instead of calling either of those, after constructing the user object, I also construct a group object, one for each group I want to see if the user is a member of.  ie, "user.IsMemberOf(group)".  That seems to work.

```
try
{
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN"))
    {
        using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName))
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                Log.Debug("UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity failed for userName = " + userName + ", thus not authorized!");
                isAuthorized = false;
            }

            if (isAuthorized)
            {
                firstName = user.GivenName;
                lastName = user.Surname;

                // so this code started failing:

                // var groups = user.GetGroups();
                // adGroups.AddRange(from @group in groups where 
                // @group.Name.ToUpper().Contains("MYSEARCHSTRING") select @group.Name);

                // so the following workaround, which calls, instead, 
                // "user.IsMemberOf(group)", 
                // appears to work (for now at least).  Will monitor for issues.

                // test membership in SuperUsers
                const string superUsersGroupName = "MyApp-SuperUsers";
                using (var superUsers = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, superUsersGroupName))
                {
                    if (superUsers != null && user.IsMemberOf(superUsers))
                        // add to the list of groups this user is a member of
                        // then do something with it later
                        adGroups.Add(superUsersGroupName);                                        
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same exception. If someone don't wanna used "LDAP", use this code. Cause I'm had nested groups, I'm used GetMembers(true) and it's little bit longer in time than GetMembers().

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27548271/1857271

or download fix from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830145

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem enumerating authorization groups and the patches noted in the answer did not apply to our web server.

Manually enumerating and ignoring the trouble causing groups is working well, however:

```
private static bool UserIsMember(string usr, string grp)
{
    usr = usr.ToLower();
    grp = grp.ToLower();

    using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN_NAME"))
    {
        using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, usr))
        {
            var isMember = false;
            var authGroups = user?.GetAuthorizationGroups().GetEnumerator();

            while (authGroups?.MoveNext() ?? false)
            {
                try
                {

                    isMember = authGroups.Current.Name.ToLower().Contains(grp);
                    if (isMember) break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }

            authGroups?.Dispose();
            return isMember;
        }
    }
}
```